# Logstash 6.2.4 stuck in infinite retry loop

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using logstash 6.2.4 with following yml settings -

```
pipeline.batch.size: 600
pipeline.workers: 1
dead_letter_queue.enable: true
```

The conf file used to run logstash application is -

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/home/administrator/Downloads/postgresql.log.2018-10-17-06"
        start_position => "beginning"
        }
}
filter {
  grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{DATESTAMP:timestamp} %{TZ}:%{IP:uip}\(%{NUMBER:num}\):%{WORD:dbuser}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}"}
}
        }
output {
   stdout { codec => rubydebug }
   elasticsearch {
   id => 'es-1'
   hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
   timeout => 60
   index => "dlq"
   version => "%{[@metadata][version]}"
   version_type => "external_gte"
 }
}
```

The input is a normal log file which is formatted using grok filter.
Here the version is always a string rather than a integer and thus elasticsearch throws error 400 Bad Request.

On this error code - logstash should retry a finite number of times and then should push this request payload to dead_letter_queue file (as per the documentation - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/dead-letter-queues.html), but it gets stuck in an infinite loop with mesaage -

[2018-10-23T12:11:42,475][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff {:code=>400, :url=>"localhost:9200/_bulk"}

Following are the contents of data/dead_letter_queue/main directory -

1.log (contains a single value "1")

Please assist if any configuration is missing leading to this situation.

Comment: Hi, `version` value type is string by default as per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.2/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-version so it should not throw an error as you stated ?  ;  Are you able to output @metadata using `stdout { codec => rubydebug { metadata => true } }`

Comment: This is the trace log - 
[2018-10-26T15:10:01,080][ERROR][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Encountered a retryable error. Will Retry with exponential backoff  {:code=>400, :url=>"localhost:9200/_bulk", :body=>"{\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"For input string: \\\"%{[@metadata][version]}\\\"\"}],\"type\":\"illegal_argument_exception\",\"reason\":\"For input string: \\\"%{[@metadata][version]}\\\"\"},\"status\":400}"}

Comment: Please check @metadata output. I am thinking maybe it should be `version => "%{[@metadata][@version]}"` , it cannot resolve `"%{[@metadata][version]}"` and perhaps throwing an illegal argument exception. I could be wrong but worth checking @metadata output

Comment: No metadata is set right now.
stdout is displaying parsed log only.
version is not a default parameter of metadata. If not set explicitly it will not exist.

Problem here is in case of 400 from elasticsearch - why DLQ of logstash did not work and it went into a infinite loop.

Comment: From documentation `The dead letter queue is only used where the response code is either 400 or 404, both of which indicate an event that cannot be "retried"` but your error entry says it encountered a retryable error so maybe because of that it is not being sent to DLQ and it keeps on retrying. Only mapping error or some other errors which **cannot be retried** are sent to DLQ from my understanding.

Comment: You could try forcing a mapping error by introducing a typo in grok filter, forcing logstash unable to parse the log and see if the event is sent to DLQ.

Comment: The error generated here is having code 400, which should not be a retryable error at all. This is probably a bug in elasticsearch output plugin.